# Difference between uvt-kvm and multipass

Tags: virtualization, cloud

These two tools seem to overlap for creating Ubuntu VMs.

Besides multipass being able to use different hypervisors, is there any difference in purpose or functionality that I might be missing?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference will be that Multipass is cross-platform, and more directed at users than Ubuntu developers. It also supports images outside of the "Ubuntu Cloud" set (like [Ubuntu Core](https://ubuntu.com/core) and [Appliances](https://ubuntu.com/appliance)).

It also is more featured, with direct support of mounts, file transfers, cloud-init and more.

Ify you want to stay tuned, we're on the [Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/multipass).